# How go to root panel when tap back ? - Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I create view for tablet.See my image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwFuu.png

In listitem in Left is Categories and listitem in right is Data.

When I tap item in left.In right is push to new panel.And When I tap item in left again.In right is push to new panel overlap.And When I tap back button is not to root panel.

**How do I put code ?**

This my code:
View:

```
Ext.define('Project-catalog.view.tablet.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'tablet-homepanel',
    requires: [ 
        'Project-catalog.store.appsAll'
    ],
    config: {
        defaultBackButtonText: 'ย้อนกลับ',
        // useTitleAsBackText: false,
        activeItem: 1,
        id: 'mynavigationview',
        title: 'All',
        iconCls: 'list',
        cls: 'home',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items:[
            {
                title: "All Apps",
                xtype: 'list',
                id:'Applist',
                store: 'appsAllID',
                itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<img src="http://61.47.41.108:9999/system/appinfos/appicons/000/000/{id}/original/{appicon_file_name}" width="50" heigh="50" style="float:left;clear:both;"></img>',
                    '<div style="margin-left: 60px;word-wrap: break-word;width:80%;">',
                    '<span style="font-size:16px;">{name}</span><br>',
                    '<span style="font-size:13px;color:#7C7C7C;" id="catname">{categoryname}</span>',
                    '</div>'    
                ),
                masked: {
                    xtype: 'loadmask',
                    message: 'Please wait'
                }
            },
            {
                width: 300,
                dock: 'left',
                title: 'Categories',
                xtype: 'tablet-navigation'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
showCatQuery: function(list,index,element,record){
        var catid = record.get('id');
        var catname = record.get('name');
        this.getHomepanel().add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: catname,
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            }, 
            items: [
                {
                    catid: catid,
                    xtype: 'tablet-showSearchCategory'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Excuse me! I'm not good english.

Comment: "In right is push to new panel overlap.And When I tap back button is not to root panel." is not clear.. can you explain ?

Comment: @Viswa when I tap item in left in right push to new panel.and tap item again in right push to new item again.When I tap back button is not to root panel